# passing an ArrayList by reference

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, reference

So I have another assignment and I am attempting to use an ArrayList object to compile a list of last names, get a count, sort in ascending order, and then sort in descending order. The issue I'm having is that Visual Studio says there is an error when I go to compile/debug but nothing is flagging and I can't seem to figure out where the issue lies.

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Collections;

   namespace Lab5_exB
   {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string anotherList;
        do
        {
            ArrayList lastNames = new ArrayList();
            string exitValue;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a last name..");
                exitValue = Console.ReadLine();
                if (exitValue == "N" || exitValue == "n")
                {
                    break;
                }
                lastNames.Add(exitValue);

            } while (exitValue != "N" || exitValue != "n");

            Console.WriteLine("Amount of last names entered: " + lastNames.Count);

            lastNames.Sort();

            Console.WriteLine("Last names in Ascending Alphabetical Order");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

            int i = 0;

            while (i < lastNames.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lastNames);
                i++;
            }

            lastNames.Reverse();

            Console.WriteLine("Last names in Descending Alphabetical Order");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

            int z = 0;

            while (z < lastNames.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lastNames);
                z++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another list? (Y/N)");
            anotherList = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());

        }while (anotherList == "Y" || anotherList == "y");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

I have written my code using separate functions and by slapping it all together into a jumbled one method/function mess. Above is the mess. Here is the separate functions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace Lab5_exB
{
class Program
{
    public static int GetLastNames(ArrayList lastNames, ref string exitValue)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a last name..");
            exitValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (exitValue == "N" || exitValue == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
            lastNames.Add(exitValue);

        } while (exitValue != "N" || exitValue != "n");
        return 0;
    }

    public static int DisplayArrayNames(ArrayList lastNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of last names entered: " + lastNames.Count);

        lastNames.Sort();

        Console.WriteLine("Last names in Ascending Alphabetical Order");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

        int i = 0; 

        while (i < lastNames.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastNames);
            i++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static int ReverseArrayNames(ArrayList lastNames)
    {
        lastNames.Sort();
        lastNames.Reverse();

        Console.WriteLine("Last names in Descending Alphabetical Order");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

        int z = 0;

        while (z < lastNames.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastNames);
            z++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string anotherList;
        do
        {
            ArrayList lastNames = new ArrayList();
            string exitValue;

            GetLastNames(lastNames);
            DisplayArrayNames(lastNames);
            ReverseArrayNames(lastNames);

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another list? (Y/N)");
            anotherList = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());

        }while (anotherList == "Y" || anotherList == "y");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

When using different functions. I receive an error that " No overload for method 'GetLastNames' takes 1 arguments " which I don't see the issue with...it appears to be written fine. When written as one method/function there is no error shown but there is 1 build error...which I assume has something to do with the code in the first "function".

I was thinking that maybe the declared functions need to be set to a string but They were flagging because they didn't return a value and I don't think I can return an ArrayList.

Any ideas?

Edit: Changed my code a bit per another's recommendation. Still receiving the "unknown" 1 failed in the build.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace Lab5_exB
{
class Program
{
    public static ArrayList GetLastNames()
    {
        string exitValue;
        var lastNames = new ArrayList();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another name? (Y/N)");
            exitValue = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());

            if (exitValue == "N" || exitValue == "n")
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a last name..");
            lastNames.Add(Console.ReadLine());

        } while (exitValue != "N" || exitValue != "n");
        return lastNames;
    }

    public static void DisplayArrayNames(ArrayList lastNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of last names entered: " + lastNames.Count);

        lastNames.Sort();

        Console.WriteLine("Last names in Ascending Alphabetical Order");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

        int i = 0; 

        while (i < lastNames.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastNames);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void ReverseArrayNames(ArrayList lastNames)
    {
        lastNames.Sort();
        lastNames.Reverse();

        Console.WriteLine("Last names in Descending Alphabetical Order");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

        int z = 0;

        while (z < lastNames.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastNames);
            z++;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string anotherList;
        do
        {
            var lastNames = GetLastNames();
            DisplayArrayNames(lastNames);
            ReverseArrayNames(lastNames);

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another list? (Y/N)");
            anotherList = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());

        }while (anotherList == "Y" || anotherList == "y");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should use `List<T>`, not `ArrayList`.

Comment: The error is quite clear. Your code has multiple redundant elements, remove them. Start with the 2nd paraneter in `int GetLastNames(ArrayList lastNames, ref string exitValue)`. It doesn't need a returnvalue either.

Comment: @Slaks: did you read the exercise description?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: `I don't think I can return an ArrayList` Wrong.

Comment: The compiler is just as offended as your brain about writing a method that returns 0 instead of a string.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: If his exercise is telling him to use non-generic collections, he should switch to a better course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your method definition:

`public static int GetLastNames(ArrayList lastNames, ref string exitValue)`

It takes two parameters. You're trying to call it with `GetLastNames(lastNames)`. You need to provide a variable for `exitValue` to the method when you call it.

That's totally aside from the actual logic.

Try this instead:

```
public static ArrayList GetLastNames()
{
    var lastNames = new ArrayList();
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a last name..");
        exitValue = Console.ReadLine();
        if (exitValue == "N" || exitValue == "n")
        {
            break;
        }
        lastNames.Add(exitValue);

    } while (exitValue != "N" || exitValue != "n");
    return lastNames;
}
```

Then call it with just `GetLastNames()`. You need to assign the result to a variable -- so you'd do this:

`var lastNames = GetLastNames();`

This takes the object created during the execution of the `GetLastNames` method and assigns it to a variable within the `Main` method.

That said, you should be using a generic collection (`List<string>`) instead of an `ArrayList` -- generic collections give you type safety. `ArrayList` is a hold-over from the .NET 1.1 days, before we had generics. For reference, the current version of the .NET Framework is 4.5.1. We've had generics since .NET 2.0, which came out almost a decade ago.

Comment: No, `exitValue` does not need a value. It needs a variable as an argumnent. Or it can be removed altogether.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for the correction -- I used the term "value" incorrectly in this case. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That looks good. The only issue I have now is that "lastNames" is not being recognized in the Main Method. I'm pretty sure I'm just a noob when it comes to this (pretty obvious). However, could you also elaborate a bit on the List<string> information?

Comment: I must be doing something completely wrong. I changed up the code a bit but I'm still having the issue with the "unknown" 1 failed build. Do I need to remove the "ArrayList lastNames" from each of the functions? If I do, how do I pass the array from function to function?

Comment: @TheNoobofNoobs When you say "it doesn't build", providing the **reason** it didn't build is important to help you troubleshoot. I'd guess that the source of the problem is the line `ArrayList lastNames = new ArrayList();`. You're declaring the `ArrayList`, then trying to re-declare it later.

Comment: Edit: Completely disregard all that. I restarted my computer and now the 1 failed build error is gone.

Comment: Now when I go to run the code. I am receiving "System.Collections.ArrayList" as the output.

Comment: This is a different problem at this point and probably warrants a new question. The problem is in `Console.WriteLine(lastNames)`. Think about why that's a problem and post a new question if you can't figure it out. I recommend doing some research on the subject first, of course. Here's a hint to help you with your debugging adventure: You're trying to print an item contained in the list, but you're passing the entire list into `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: I figured it out. I setup a foreach loop instead of a while loop in the 2nd and 3rd method. I was approaching that issue incorrectly. Thank you very much for your help though. I appreciate it.